# While loop stuck infinitely with else statement, despite using continue

Tags: c, while-loop, int, scanf

I'm currently trying to get a users input and see if it is valid, i.e whether or not they have entered an integer versus a string, however, my program does work in realizing the user hasn't entered an integer given it goes to the else statement, except it doesn't restart the loop but rather just prints the words "please try again" a million times in a infinite loop. I've tried implementing the continue statement, but it seems to create the same issue, any input would be much appreciated!

Here is a snippet:

```
int userInput;
int exit;
exit = 0;

while(exit == 0)
{
    if(scanf("%d",&userInput) == 1)
        function(userInput);
    else
        printf("Please try again!\n"); //This loops infinite times, doesn't restart the loop and    check input again like the first if
    continue;
 }
```

Comment: exit is always 0 in this snip.  where is it ever set to some value other than zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
scanf("%*s");
```

Inside the body of the `else` to remove the invalid input from the `stdin`. You might also want to set `exit` to 1 when `scanf` is successful in order to prevent an infinite loop. So modify your code to:

```
int userInput;
int exit;
exit = 0;

while(exit == 0)
{
    if(scanf("%d",&userInput) == 1) {
        function(userInput);
        exit=1;
    }       
    else
    {
        printf("Please try again!\n");
        scanf("%*s");
    }
 }
```

Comment: What? What do you mean by "loop stops altogether after that"?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3852934/3788

> The original code loops indefinitely because the invalid data (the
>   "gfggdf") is not removed from the input buffer when scanf fails to
>   convert it to an integer -- it's left in the input buffer, so the next
>   call to scanf looks at the same data, and (of course) still can't
>   convert it to an integer, so the loop executes yet again, and the
>   results still haven't changed.