# While loop misbehaving,

Tags: c

i am pretty new to c, i m trying to make the user input a number, but if they input a letter or word it shows a warning and asks for input again, my code works fine if the user puts in a number but it goes into an infinite loop if the user inputs something invalid, here is my code

```
   #include <stdio.h>


    int main(void) {
      float salary;
      int status = 0;
      
      while (status == 0)
      {
        printf(" Please input your yearly salary to calculate taxes: \n");
        status = scanf(" %f", &salary);
        if (status == 0)
         printf("invalid input!\n");
      } 
      printf("%.2f\n", salary);
      return 0;
    }
```

i thought that i was something to do with the buffer left over from the first scanf , but adding a space " %f" didnt work, i tried using fflush(stdin) after then scanf also didnt work. i m not sure what else i can try.

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but scanning a float into a long probably won't get you what you want.

Comment: oh yeah, i accidentally left that as a long by mistake while i was tinkering with it. i addressed it, didn't solve the problem tho. thanks!

Comment: show us what the output looks like, including the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the buffer or it will keep evaluating it and cause the endless loop.  Add one line after your invalid input: scanf("%*[^\n]")

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
  float salary;
  int status = 0;
  
  while (status == 0)
  {
    printf(" Please input your yearly salary to calculate taxes: \n");
    status = scanf(" %f", &salary);
    if (status == 0)
     printf("invalid input!\n");
     scanf("%*[^\n]");     
  } 
  printf("%.2f\n", salary);
  return 0;
}
```

This will work.  You can see a better explanation here: [Scanf and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852789/scanf-and-loops)

Comment: Thanks that worked! but  i have no idea what the line scanf("%*[^\n]") does, do you mind explaining it please ?

Comment: @IvoBiz — You could study the POSIX specification of [`scanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html), or the standard C specification: [§7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2).  But it reads a sequence of characters up to but not including a newline (using the negated 'scan set' `[^\n]`) and doesn't assign it to anything because of the `*`.  It reads whatever else is left on the line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `scanf` won't advance the file stream.  You ask it to read a floating point value and it isn't able to, so it doesn't consume the input.

For example, let's say your input is "foo", which isn't a number.  Your `scanf` call isn't able to successfully read anything and returns 0.  Then, in the next iteration, "foo" is still waiting to be read from stdin.

Try changing your if condition to something like

```c
if (status == 0) {
  char foo[256];
  fgets(foo, sizeof(foo), stdin);
  printf("Invalid input! Expected a nmuber, got: %s", foo);
}
```

Notice how the entire input is read from stdin by the `gets` call.

Comment: i have no idea how the fgets command works. i need to read up on that. Thank you for the reply tho. i ll study it more.

Comment: Note that `scanf()` works on a file stream, not a file descriptor.